# Получение ip-адреса по доменному имени

Tags: java

Как в `Java` можно легко получить `ip-адрес` по доменному имени хоста ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
InetAddress.getByName("domain")
```

Гугл сразу ответит Вам что-то в таком духе:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462398/how-to-get-the-ip-address-from-the-domain-name-in-java